# Why Can't We Use The MLA Lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Consider the following diagram with stated conditions,
[image]

Using the ML lemma, it is possible to show that $$\int_{\Gamma_1} f(z) \ dz\rightarrow 0\ \ \text{as} \ \ R\rightarrow\infty, \ \ \text{as} \ \ \left|\int_{\Gamma_1} f(z) \ dz\right|\leq\frac{2\pi}{R}.$$

> My question is, why can we not use a similar computation to find $$\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{\Gamma_3} f(z) \ dz?$$

Comment: Because that limit is nonzero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\Gamma_3$, we can write
\begin{align*}
\lim_{r\to0}\int_{\Gamma_3}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z&=\lim_{r\to0}\int_\pi^0 \frac{1-e^{ire^{i\theta}}}{r^2e^{2i\theta}}\,rie^{i\theta}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&= \lim_{r\to0}\;i\int_0^\pi\frac{e^{ire^{i\theta}}-1}{re^{i\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&= \lim_{r\to0}\;i\int_0^\pi \frac{\left(1+ire^{i\theta}-\frac{1}{2}r^2e^{2i\theta}+\cdots\right)-1}{re^{i\theta}}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&= \lim_{r\to0}\,i\int_0^\pi\left(i-\frac{1}{2}re^{i\theta}-\frac{i}{6}r^2e^{2i\theta}+\cdots\right)\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&= \,-1\int_0^\pi1\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=-\pi
\end{align*}

Comment: Yep, I have done this haha but I was wondering why we can't use the ML lemma to show this result

Comment: Because you can only find an upper bound for the modulus of integral using ML lemma. Since the integral is complex valued, the only time you can deduce the value of the integral using ML is if that upper bound is zero.

Comment: Does that mean that $$\lim_{r\to \lambda}\int_{\Gamma} f(z) \ dz$$ can only be computed by the ML lemma when $\lambda\neq 0$?

Comment: Nope, that's not what i meant. ML lemma does not say anything about computability of the integral. You can only directly deduce the value of the integral if the upper bound given by ML is zero, or similarly you can take a limit and if the upper bound goes to zero in that limit, than the value of the integral in that limit will be zero. For example, in your case, you found that $\left|\int_{\Gamma_1} f(z) \ dz\right|\leq\frac{2\pi}{R}$ and since $\frac{2\pi}{R}$ goes to $0$ as $R$ goes to infinity, you can infer that value of the integral will be zero as $R$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. But is there a way to determine that $\left|\int_{\Gamma_3} f(z) \ dz\right|\nrightarrow 0$ as $r\rightarrow 0$ using the ML lemma by inspection? I'm just wondering how to determine which method to use upon first glance of the question.

Comment: Well, basically you found $\left|\int_{\Gamma_1}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\leq\frac{2\pi}{R}$, you can just substitute $r$ for $R$ and get $\left|\int_{\Gamma_3}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\leq\frac{2\pi}{r}$. Then, since $\frac{2\pi}{r}$ does not tend to zero but instead goes to infinity as $r\to0$, we cannot deduce that $\left|\int_{\Gamma_3}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\to0$. But note that we cannot deduce $\left|\int_{\Gamma_3}f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z\right|\to0$ either since the upper bound is infinite. So, in general, i don't know if there is a way knowing whether an integral is nonzero.

Comment: Also, are you missing a factor of $i$ throughout you calculations (where you evaluated the Taylor series)?